# Fast and Easy way to mask ground of CGI element?

Tags: compositing

This shot has parallax as the camera is booming from high to low. I have a cloudpoint camera track in Blender but I'm trying to figure out how I can mask the ground of the tunnel so that it doesn't look like it is on the edge of the cliff but actually driving into the wall behind that edge. (obviously dealing with blur, light wrap and everything else after). I would basically need to duplicate the live action plate, mask the portion I want to use to hide about a quarter of the tunnel and bring the layer up but that would mean having to camera track irregular lines and I don't know how good it would come out. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Tracking and rotoscoping are really your only option, but asking on the Blender SE might at least get you app-specific advice on that.  Here, I’d have to point you towards Mocha or Silhouette, which might be overkill, depending on the shot.